# Can't get bfg-repo-cleaner work

Tags: github, bfg-repo-cleaner

I was trying to use [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove a large file from git history, but can't get it work. Please help!

1. I downloaded the latest BFG *bfg-1.12.12.jar*
2. Then I tried to clone a fresh copy of my repo:

   ```
   $ git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
   ```

Here comes the problem, it says:

> fatal: unable to connect to example.com:
>   example.com[0: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]: errno=Operation timed out
>   example.com[1: 93.184.216.34]: errno=Operation timed out

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm assuming you're cloning from your own repo's URL and not `example.com`, right?

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't use `example.com`. I finally solved it by cloning from my own repo's URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to download a copy of your repo from `example.com` (resolves to `93.184.216.34`).

Think about where the main copy of your repo is. It's *not* on example.com, is it?

You need to use the actual address of your repo, not the example url given in the BFG docs.

It's possible you're not using a Git hosting service, in which case you would just use the local file path to the repo instead of a remote address.